# Ruby on Rails - group_by for relation and created_at

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking for a Rails query that will get me the last created rating for every movie made by the current user.

For example, let's say I have this active record collection:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [
  #<Rating id: 115, score: 5, movie_id: 7, user_id: 5, created_at: "2019-09-16 16:47:55", updated_at: "2019-09-16 16:47:55">,
  #<Rating id: 116, score: 3, movie_id: 7, user_id: 5, created_at: "2019-09-16 16:47:57", updated_at: "2019-09-16 16:47:57">,
  #<Rating id: 117, score: 5, movie_id: 7, user_id: 5, created_at: "2019-09-16 16:50:37", updated_at: "2019-09-16 16:50:37">,
  #<Rating id: 118, score: 3, movie_id: 8, user_id: 5, created_at: "2019-09-16 16:50:42", updated_at: "2019-09-16 16:50:42">
]>
```

We can see there are three objects with `movie_id`: `7`, one with `movie_id`: `6`. This is wrong as I need to get the latest rating for each movie from the current_user.

For example, something alone the lines of this:

```
Rating.order(created_at: :desc).select('DISTINCT ON (movie_id) *')
```

My model associations:

```
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many   :ratings, dependent: :destroy
end

class Rating < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :movie
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :movies
  has_many :ratings
end
```

Please explain the Rails query as I really want to understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do it in parts!

You need a Rails query that will get me the last created rating for every movie made by the current user.

Ok, with this information, let`s start with the current_user reference!

Your relation for `User` is like this:

> A `user` has many `movies`
>
> A `user` has many `ratings`

With these definitions, you can take advantage of ActiveRecord to run the following methods:

```rb
current_user.movies # All movies of a current_user
current_user.movies # All ratings of a current_user
```

Ok, now we can access all movies and ratings from a user instance, but how we can access the ratings grouped by movies?

Let's see the `Rating` relations:

> A `rating` belongs to a `user` # this means the rating instance has the user_id
>
> A `rating` belongs to a `movie` # this means the rating instance has the movie_id

Nice! Now we can **get the user ratings grouped by `movie`**:

```rb
current_user.ratings.group_by { |rating| rating.movie_id }
# or the sugar sintax
grouped_ratings = current_user.ratings.group_by(&:movie_id)
```

This will group all user ratings based on the `movie_id`, and will produce to us a hash like:

```rb
{
  1: [#<Rating id: 115...#>, #<Rating id: 116...#>], # The "1" means the movie_id of the group_by
  2: [#<Rating id: 117...#>] # The "2" means the movie_id of the group_by
}
```

Ok, now we have a hash of ratings from a User, grouped by the `movie_id`.

But we need the last rating created by a user for each Movie correctly?

```rb
last_ratings_for_each_movie = grouped_ratings.map do |movie_id, ratings|
  movie = Movie.find(movie_id)
  last_rating = ratings.sort_by{ |rating| rating.created_at }.last
  
  puts "The last Rating created by the current user for Movie #{movie.title} is the rating #{last_rating.id}" # Assuming movie has a title
  
  last_rating
end
```

In the last moment, you will have an array of the last rating created for a movie (to access the movie you can execute a `rating.movie` for example)

I didn't understand if you must do it with SQL, if yes, let me know pls :)

Hope it helps!

Comment: What an amazing answer. Thank you, I actually understand it now :)

Comment: I'm running the code and we are having a slight problem where we call order. NoMethodError: undefined method `order' for #<Array:0x00007fefe599fed0>. Maybe we should use sort_by instead?

Comment: Try to replace `ratings.order(created_at: :desc).first` to `ratings.sort_by{ |rating| rating.created_at }.last`

Comment: Ok I need to see also if I have access to the relations in the .js.erb view, since it has turned to an array.

Comment: The new sort_by has somehow turned it into a multidimensional array and doesn't filter as before. https://imgur.com/a/S09eY2M https://imgur.com/a/2qOEZfL

Comment: Don't forget the `.last` in the final of `sort_by`

Comment: Wonderful, it looks great now! Thanks for the awesome help.

Comment: I hope this will help someone else.